# moving ngfor data outside of it's tag

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

it's my first time posting so critic for etiquette.

been using *ngFor="let item of items" in a ionic project but I ran into a problem, that being that once *ngFor is used in the a tag, I don't know who I can transfare the data for a selected item into a tag that is outside of the original tag containing it.

code:

```
<ion-list>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ion-item-group class="day" *ngFor="let day of Excursion_Schedule" >
    <ion-item-divider class="dayCard" (click)="day.displayItineraryFlag= !day.displayItineraryFlag"><ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>{{day.ExcSch_date | date:'dd'}}</ion-item-divider>
       <!-- CODE I WANT TO MOVE   --> <ng-container *ngIf="day.displayItineraryFlag">
      <div ion-item class="cardtitle" *ngFor="let place of day.Excursion_CustomRoadMap">
        <p>check</p>
          <ion-item-divider class="cardtitle" *ngIf="place.Exc_CustomRoadMap_Name" (click)="place.displayStationDetailsFlag= !place.displayStationDetailsFlag">
             <div class="textW">{{place.Description}} - {{place.Exc_CustomRoadMap_StartTime}}</div>
             <br>
             <div *ngIf="place.displayStationDetailsFlag">
              <div class="mapNpic">
                <img class="pics" src="{{place.Photo}}" alt="">
                <img class="pics" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/14/5f/96/77/nice-view-of-the-sunset.jpg" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="dits">
                <br> <br>
                <h3>Adress</h3>
                <h3>Phone Number</h3>
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <h3>Website</h3>
                



              </div>

             </div>
          </ion-item-divider> 
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item-group>
</div>
<p>
  TESTING 123
  <!-- PLACE WHERE I WANT TO MOVE ng-container TO   -->
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use interpolation. To achieve this you have to write the selected item into a variable and then interpolate it into the outer area. Here is an example:

***TS***

```
selectedItem: any;
Excursion_Schedule: Array<any> = [];
```

***HTML***

```
<div><span>{{selectedItem}}</span>
    
    <div *ngFor="let day of Excursion_Schedule">
        <!-- write the selected day into the local variable here -->
    </div>

</div>
```